# Create cross domain cookies for single sign on

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, cookies

I want to implement single sign on from my website(assume it as a.com) to vendor website(assume it as b.com)

My vendor is providing a service which will take user Id as input and returns token and cookies in response header. I need to call this service and redirect to vendor url with session token through post request and set cookies(which are received from service response).

In my code after making service call i am returning url and token to a jsp and cookies in httpservletresponse . Javascript in this jsp will autosubmit the form on page load to make post call. But when it is redirected, browser is not setting the b.com cookies in the request header.

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sso", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ssoToVendor(final Model model, final HttpServletResponse response) {
   /**
    *Service call happens here and returns tok
    */
    model.addAttribute("url","https:\\b.com");
    model.addAttribute("tok",tok);
    for (String cookie : cookies) {
        response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);
    }

    return "dummyjsp"
}
```

JSP sample code :

```
    <body>
  <form id="redirect" action="${url}" name="redirect" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="tok" id="tok" value="${tok}"/> 
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var redirect  = document.getElementById("redirect");
redirect.submit();

</script>
```

I know that it is not possible to set cross domain cookies but some how there is another application which is implemented in c# is able to set those cookies.

Is there a way we can set b.com cookies in response header and that is created by browser and sent to b.com when redirected from a.com in java.